# Shapes and their point ids. Shape ids are different but point ids are consecutively incremented

Tags: c++

**Requirement:**

```
Shape ID: 0 (say rectangle)  
Point IDs in rectangle: 0, 1, 2 and 3.
    
Shape ID: 1 (say square)
Point IDs in square: 0, 1, 2 and 3.
```

I wrote a code by for creating a shape and adding points to each shape. Classes Shape and LBP are defined.

**Problem:**

The point IDs are not starting from '0' in shape 1. Ideally, the point IDs in shape 1 (square )should start from 0 rather than 1. I feel that is the program appending the newly created point to the point set of the previous shape object i.e. shape 0 (rectangle).

```
Shape ID: 0 (say rectangle)
Point IDs: 0
Shape ID: 1 (say square)
Point IDs: 1
```

**Question:** How to make the point ids start from '0' for every new shape created?

The classes defined are as shown below.

MasterDefine.h

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


class LBP
{
private:
    double  x, y;
    int     pointID;
    static int pointCount;
public:
    void    setLBP(double, double);
    void    getLBP(double&, double&);
    void    addLBPatEnd();
    void    addLBPatLocation();
    void    delLBPatEnd();
    void    delLBPatLocation(int);
    void    setLBPID();
    int     getLBPID();
    void    goToNode(int);
    int     getNoOfPoints();
    LBP(double, double);
    ~LBP();
    LBP* next, * prev;
};

class Shape
{
private:
    int shapeID;
    static int shapeCount;

public:
    void setShapeID();
    int  getShapeID();
    LBP* points;
    Shape();

};
```

Main.cpp

```
#include"MasterDefine.h"
int LBP::pointCount = 0;
int Shape::shapeCount = 0;
LBP* lbp, *firstPt, *lastPt;
void printLBPForward();
void printLBPReverse();
void delLBP(int);
void delAllLBPs();


int main()
{
    cout << endl << "Hello world" << endl;

    Shape* shape0 = new Shape;
    cout << endl << "Shape id is " << shape0->getShapeID() << endl; //gives id of shape0

    LBP* s0p0 = new LBP(22, 33); //point 0 of shape 0
    shape0->points = s0p0;

    Shape* shape1 = new Shape;
    cout << endl << "Shape id is " << shape1->getShapeID() << endl; //gives id of shape1
    LBP* s1p0 = new LBP(10, 5);//point 0 of shape 1
    shape1->points = s1p0;

    cout << endl << "point id is " << s1p0->getLBPID() << endl;
    
    return 1;
}
```

LBP.cpp

```
#include"MasterDefine.h"
//#include "LBP.h"

LBP* lbpFirst, *lbpLast;

void LBP::getLBP(double& getX, double& getY)
{
    getX = x;
    getY = y;
}

void LBP::addLBPatEnd()
{
//  cout << endl << "add lbp at end " << endl;
//  cout << endl << "Pointer value in member function " << this << endl;
    LBP* tempNode;

    if (getNoOfPoints() == 1)
    {
        tempNode = this;
        tempNode->next = NULL;
        tempNode->prev = NULL;
        lbpFirst = tempNode;
    }
    if (getNoOfPoints() == 2)
    {
        tempNode = this;
        lbpFirst->next = tempNode;
        lbpFirst->prev = tempNode;
        tempNode->next = tempNode->prev = lbpFirst;
        lbpLast = tempNode;
    }

    if (getNoOfPoints() > 2)
    {
        tempNode = this;
        lbpLast->next = tempNode;
        tempNode->next = lbpFirst;
        lbpFirst->prev = tempNode;
        tempNode->prev = lbpLast;
        lbpLast = tempNode;
    }
    
    //goToNode();
}

void LBP::delLBPatEnd()
{
    LBP* tempNodeDel;
    tempNodeDel = lbpFirst;
    do
    {
        tempNodeDel = tempNodeDel->next;
    } while (tempNodeDel->getLBPID() != pointCount - 2);
    cout << endl << "tempNodeDel id is " << tempNodeDel->getLBPID() << endl;

    tempNodeDel->next = lbpFirst;
    lbpFirst->prev = tempNodeDel;

    
}

void LBP::delLBPatLocation(int NodePos)
{
    LBP* TempNodePosDel, *TempNodePosDelPrev, *TempNodePosDelNext;
    TempNodePosDel = lbpFirst;
    do
    {
        TempNodePosDel = TempNodePosDel->next;
    } while (TempNodePosDel->getLBPID() != NodePos);

    cout<<endl<<"NodeID that is to be deleted is "<<TempNodePosDel->getLBPID()<<endl;
    cout << endl << "TempNodePosDel" << TempNodePosDel << endl;


    
    TempNodePosDelPrev = TempNodePosDel->prev;
    TempNodePosDelNext = TempNodePosDel->next;

    cout << endl << "TempNodePosDelPrev id is " << TempNodePosDelPrev->getLBPID() << endl;
    cout << endl << "TempNodePosDel id is " << TempNodePosDel->getLBPID() << endl;
    cout << endl << "TempNodePosDelNext id is " << TempNodePosDelNext->getLBPID() << endl;

    TempNodePosDelPrev->next = TempNodePosDelNext;
    TempNodePosDelNext->prev = TempNodePosDelPrev; 
    
    cout << endl << "************************************" << endl;

    cout << endl << "TempNodePosDelPrev " << TempNodePosDelPrev << endl;
    cout << endl << "TempNodePosDelPrev->next " << TempNodePosDelPrev->next << endl;
    cout << endl << "TempNodePosDelNext->prev " << TempNodePosDelNext->prev << endl;
    cout << endl << "TempNodePosDelNext " << TempNodePosDelNext << endl;
    

    cout << endl << "************************************" << endl;

}

void LBP::setLBPID()
{
    pointID = pointCount;
}

int LBP::getLBPID()
{
    return pointID;
}

void LBP::goToNode(int)
{

}

int LBP::getNoOfPoints()
{
    return pointCount;
}

LBP::LBP(double setX, double setY)
{
    x = setX;
    y = setY;
    setLBPID();
    pointCount++;
    addLBPatEnd();
    
}

LBP::~LBP()
{
    cout << endl << "In destructor " << endl;
    int NodePosForDel;
    NodePosForDel = this->getLBPID();
    if (NodePosForDel != 1)
    {
        delLBPatLocation(NodePosForDel);
    }
    /*delLBPatEnd();*/
    

    cout << endl << "this pointer in destructor " << this << endl;
    pointCount--;
}
```

Shape.cpp

```
#include"MasterDefine.h"

void Shape::setShapeID()
{
    shapeID = shapeCount;
}

int Shape::getShapeID()
{
    return shapeID;
}

Shape::Shape()
{
    setShapeID();
    shapeCount++;
}
```

Console output:

```
Shape id is 0
point id is 0

Shape id is 1
point id is 1
```

Can anyone help me in this? I am definitely missing something. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

> Question: How to make the point ids start from '0' for every new shape created?

Since your `static int pointCount;` member is static, it's the same member variable for all instances of `class LBP`, and because the instances share the member, upon creating a new instance, it has access to the changes made to this variable by all previous instances here:

```
LBP::LBP(double setX, double setY)
{
    ...
    pointCount++;
    ...
    
}
```

This value is definitely not supposed to be stored statically, and it's neither responsibility of a vertex to store number of all vertices in a shape. Make a non-static variable of `class Shape` for example and keep that information there:

```
class Shape
{
private:
    size_t verticesNum;
    ...
```

Comment: I removed the static keyword in front of the pointCount and shapeCount. Now the output is the following:

Shape id is 0
point id is 0

Shape id is 0
point id is 0